# Here documents as multiple lines command within the bash

Tags: bash

I created a snippet to test the here document

```
$ cat test101.sh
ls
$ bash test101.sh
bmdt.md       brmdh.md  fild.md  test     test101.sh  test2  test5  testfile
breakfast.md  exec  file.md  test.sh  test12      test3  test7
```

It come to Here document

```
$ $(cat << EOF
→ ls
→ EOF)
bmdt.md       brmdh.md  fild.md  test     test101.sh  test2  test5  testfile
breakfast.md  exec  file.md  test.sh  test12      test3  test7
```

It works properly,
Unfortunately, it's not the case of structured command

```
$ $(cat << EOF
→ for i in *
→ do 
→   stat $i
→ done
→ EOF)
-bash: for: command not found
```

I tried alternatively

```
$ bash $(cat << EOF
→ for i in *
→ do
→   stat $i
→ done
→ EOF)
bash: for: No such file or directory
```

What's the problem not allow the for command working?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using loop inside heredoc?

Comment: learning to get a better understanding about how heredoc work. @user1700494

Comment: You'd need to escape the special characters, e.g. `*` -> `\*`, `$i` -> `\$i`

Comment: @steve The `*` does not need special treatment as the shell won't do filename globbing on the contents of the document, only expansions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A here-document is a form of redirection.  In your commands, you redirect into the `cat` command, and then try to use the output as a command in a command substitution.

1. `$i` will be expanded when the contents of the here-document is formed.  This happens long before the loop in the document actually runs.  If the `i` variable is unset, it will expand to an empty string. You may choose to quote the here-document (by quoting the first `EOF` as `'EOF'` or `\EOF`) so that no expansions are done in it, or to explicitly escape the `$` as `\$` to protect it from expansion.
2. The contents of the here-document will be interpreted as a single string with new-line delimited lines. It will not undergo the usual token recognition and other steps involved in the parsing of ordinary commands, but will be split up into individual words since the command substitution is unquoted.  In particular, `for` will not be recognised as a shell keyword.  This is why your first failing example fails. To re-evaluate the string, you would have to `eval` it, which would re-evaluate the string as the shell would have done had it been given on the command line.
3. The last example would expand to `bash` followed by a number of words.  The first word is `for`, so `bash` would expect to run a shell script called `for` in the current directory, but fails in doing so.
4. In all examples, `bash` *should* also have complained that the here-document was not properly terminated (since the last line is `EOF)` with a trailing right parenthesis, not `EOF`), saying something like

   ```
   bash: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
   ```

   unless you are using an older `bash` release, like the default one on macOS.

Instead, this would be a better choice of actions as it avoids converting code into a string that needs to be re-interpreted and instead gives the document as a in-line shell script directly to a shell interpreter to execute.

```
bash <<'END_SCRIPT'
for i in *; do
    printf 'Filename: "%s"\n' "$i"
done
END_SCRIPT
```

The first of your examples work because it's a simple command.